# Import stl script blender

Tags: python, import, blender, stl-format

What I am trying to do is import a .stl model into blender using a script (in python). I have tried using the command below but I can't seem to get it to work. The problem is I don't know the format of the "Filepath", "files", and "directory" part of the command.

```
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath="", filter_glob="*.stl", files=None, directory="")
```

Can someone please show me how to get this working; that is all I ask.

```
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath="C://Users//Dom//Documents//DomCorp.//mymodel.stl", filter_glob="*.stl", files=None, directory="")
```

When I write this I get this errror:

```
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties:  IMPORT_MESH_OT_stl.files expected a each sequence member to be a dict for an RNA collection, not str
```

Since I am fairly new to programming I don't know what it means so can someone help and explain it and possibly come up with a fix?? :)

Comment: What did you try? What where the results? Please provide more info on what you already did.

Comment: I have added a bit more info is it enough???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to work this out!! :D

This seems to work:

```
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath="C://Users//Dom//Documents//DomCorp.//mymodel.stl", filter_glob="*.stl",  files=[{"name":"mymodel.stl", "name":"mymodel.stl"}], directory="C://Users//Dom//Documents//DomCorp.")
```

Comment: Can confirm this works in Linux too, but for me also the slightly more minimal (no `files` dict required): `bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=abs_filename_with_folder , filter_glob="*.stl", directory=folder)`

Answer (score 7):

The "filepath" parameter should be sufficient as the others are optional:

```
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath="C://Users//Dom//Documents//DomCorp//mymodel.stl")
```